# fillColors style seems not working for Button

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I use mx.controls.Button control and I'm trying to change its colors:

```
import mx.controls.Button;

//...

var myButton:Button = new Button();
myButton.width = 70;
myButton.height = 30;
myButton.label = 'test';
myButton.setStyle('fillColors', [0x0f9f4f, 0x0f9f4f, 0x006600, 0x006633]);
addChild(myButton);
```

and it doesn't work. However cornerRadius style and many others work well.
How do I change colors of the button?

What's wrong with it? How do I setup color for a button?

Answer (score 0):

fillColors takes two parameters, not four.

ex: `setStyle('fillColors', [0x000000, 0xFFFFFF])`

are you trying to set fillAlpha too?

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=skinstyle_3.html
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=skinning_8.html

Comment: Changed to 2 params. Still not working. fillAlphas dosn't work too.

Comment: trying adding the button first and then call the setStyle method.